# Test-Path is erroring instead of returning True/False

Tags: powershell

This is very straight forward. I'm writing a powershell function and I want to validate if a parameter is a valid directory, but instead of returning `True` or `False`, `Test-Path` is erroring?

This is counter to what I'm reading about the behavior of the function.

```
if (Test-Path -PathType Container "asdf")
{
    Write-Output "Exists"
}
else
{
    Write-Output "Does not exist"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in the SQLSERVER drive. You need to change your location back to a FileSystem drive.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize powershell on SQL server would be in some sort of drive. Is there a standard way to default to a FileSystem drive or do I just `Set-Location $PSScriptRoot`?

Answer (score 2):

The answer you accepted is right, but I wanted to expand on what you can do differently.

This was a problem up until very recently. [PowerShell's SQL server support has been vastly improved](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2016/06/30/sql-powershell-july-2016-update/), so much so that they created a new module for it, so if you're still using `SQLPS` look into using the `SqlServer` module instead.

With `SQLPS`, it automatically changes the drive to the `SQLSERVER:` provider.

If you must continue using or supporting `SQLPS` and want to avoid this behavior (it can also make tab completing super slow), I'm fond of this pattern:

```
Push-Location
Import-Module SQLPS
Pop-Location
```

This saves your current location in the location stack, imports the module (which will change your location), then pops your previous location back off, so you're back where you started.

I strongly encourage you to look at using the new module as it has some really important enhancements and improvements.

Comment: Great info! I'm a dev, but still growing my powershell base and love learning new things.

Answer (score 0):

You're set up in the SQLSERVER drive. You need to be back in your local file system. Go ahead and do a

```
Set-Location C:
```

Then you will be able to run your If statement.

I would have commented this onto the first answer that was given to clarify how to get to the local file system, but my low reputation restricts me from commenting.